# Does using .remove in a if statement removes the contents inside?

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

```
public class StackOverFlow{
    ArrayList x = new ArrayList<String>();
    x.add("nice");
    y = "wew";

    if(x.remove.equals(y))
        x.remove(0);
}
```

The code above is only an example.

Would this code result in `x` having `IndexOutofBoundsException` since the element inside was already removed from the `if` statement?

Comment: I assume you mean `if(x.remove(0).equals(y)))`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every call to `remove` on `List` will remove an object, it doesn't matter where you call it.

Answer (score 1):

Two types of remove functions exists in `ArrayList`. If you have a copy of an object that you want to remove from the list, you can pass it as an argument to the `remove` function itself. 
[JAVA7-ArrayList-Ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Example:

```
x.remove(y) // returns a boolean value true when the first occurrence of object y is remove from list x
```